# error: `itoa` was not declared in this scope

Tags: c

I have a sample c file called itoa.cpp as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  int i;
  char buffer [33];
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  itoa (i,buffer,10);
  printf ("decimal: %s\n",buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

When i compile the above code with the below command:

```
gcc itoa.cpp -o itoa
```

i am getting this error:

```
[root@inhyuvelite1 u02]# gcc itoa.cpp -o itoa
itoa.cpp: In function "int main()":
itoa.cpp:10: error: "itoa" was not declared in this scope
```

What is wrong in this code? How to get rid of this?

Comment: You are using gcc to compile a file named .cpp, this will compile it as C, not only that but all of the headers you are including are standard C library.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

itoa is not ansi C standard and you should probably avoid it.  Here are some roll-your-own implementations if you really want to use it anyway:

http://www.strudel.org.uk/itoa/

If you need in memory string formatting, a better option is to use snprintf.  Working from your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  int i;
  char buffer [33];
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", i);
  printf ("decimal: %s\n",buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are only interested in base 10, 8 or 16. you can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf(buf,"%d",i);
```

Comment: If i use the snprintf as mentioned Mikola, and compile the program as: gcc itoa.cpp -o itoa, i am getting the this error: [root@inhyuvelite1 u02]# gcc itoa.cpp -o itoa
/tmp/ccUB2wBP.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You should probably recommend snprintf over sprintf.

Comment: @user771245: You are compiling C++ code with a C compiler. Use g++. Or rename your file to itoa.c

Comment: you mean sprintf or snprintf are c++ functions? I am asking this becuase, we have to use itoa function in on of our existing program where the file is stored with .cpp extension but we compile with gcc. I am new to c/c++, please expalin me in more detail. We write only c code in .cpp files and compile with gcc. Recently we have to modify our code to use itoa function i don't know whether it is a c function or c++ function. Assuming i save the file with .cpp extension and run with gcc, can't i use itoa? If not, is there any other function that give same result as itoa or sprintf or snprintf?

Comment: @user771245: Usually `gcc` is for `.c` files and `g++` is for `.cpp` files.

Comment: @vchitta: `itoa` is simply not part of the default c or c++. Some compiler setups (really the system libraries) will provide that function. `snprintf` and `sprintf` are usually drop-in replacements for that function that is supported everywhere. That's why we are suggesting it. On the subject of a C or C++ function, `snprintf` and `sprintf` are C functions, that are available for use under C++ as well. The C++ exclusive equivalent would be using `stringstreams` and the `<<` and `>>` operators. (Or using `boost::lexical_cast`).

Answer (score 4):

Look into stdlib.h. Maybe _itoa instead itoa was defined there.

Comment: That was my case. #include <stdlib.h>